# Finding a key binding definition in CodeRush

Tags: devexpress, coderush

If I deployed a Community plugin and set up a key-binding in CodeRush, how do I now find where I filed it in the options dialog / tree hierarchy ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the CodeRush options screen (Either choose **DevExpress \ Options** from the menu or hit **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O**)

Then locate **IDE \ Shortcuts** folder in the page hierarchy on  the left.

Above the shortcut tree, there is a toolbar containing several buttons which are useful in different circumstances.

[image: Shortcut Hierarchy Toolbar]

In this case the following 2 options may be of some use.

Option 1 - **Search**

- The 2nd last icon on the toolbar (a magnifying glass) is a search facility which can be used to search for shortcuts.
- You can search by folder, key binding, mouse binding or by command name.

[image: The Shortcut Search Dialog]

Option 2 - **Flatten hierarchy and sort**.

- Click third last icon in the toolbar (a folder) to collapse the hierarchy.
- You'll now be viewing the same set of shortcuts in a flat grid rather than in a tree.
- You should now be able to sort by either Shortcut or Command and easily locate the binding you're after.

We recommend placing user created bindings in a **custom** root folder within the hierarchy so as to easily distinguish between your own shortcuts and those shipped with CodeRush.

This can also ease transferal of these shortcuts to other machines since this will cause said shortcuts to be placed in a file of their own.

Comment: I would have also +1 because of the tip about filing them in a custom folder.

Answer (score 3):

In the CodeRush Options Dialog

IDE \ Shortcuts.

Click the 'find' magnifying glass.

on the 'Key Shortcut' tab type the keybinding of the command you bound.

Or, on the 'command' tab, type part of the plugin name.

Job Done.

Thanks.