# Backing up my Custom Settings in CodeRush

Tags: devexpress, coderush

In [Finding a key binding definition in CodeRush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620520/finding-a-key-binding-definition-in-coderush/5620584#5620584) @RoryBecker advocated putting all my custom keyboard shortcuts in a 'custom' folder.  How do I ensure these settings are backed up, and also so that I can copy those settings from one development machine to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create all new shortcuts within a "**Custom**" folder then the file you'll need to backup is "**Settings.XML\IDE\Shortcuts_Custom.xml**" folder

The location of the **Settings.XML** folder will vary depending on your system and it's settings.

See [this blogpost](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2011/04/11/coderush-tip-where-are-my-coderush-settings-stored.aspx) general help on settings and their location